# Error when injecting Repository dependency with Koin

Tags: android, repository, retrofit, retrofit2, koin

I have a repository which can be injected into one interceptor but which fails to be resolved when injected into another one at runtime.

The logcat points to a problem with Koin's handling of the repository’s dependencies itself but I’m not exactly sure what and why. It does repeatedly refer to "Unknown Source:4" which points to a SharedPreferences import but perhaps that's a distraction.

I'm still new to Dependency Injection and Koin, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot! :)

Here’s an sample, edited snippet of my logcat (hope it's enough):

```
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at xxxxx.app.presentation.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$9.invoke(modules.kt:370)
        at xxxxx.app.presentation.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$9.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at xxxxx.app.presentation.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$4.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:214)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
        at xxx.app.presentation.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$4.invoke(modules.kt:375)
        at xxx.app.presentation.di.ModulesKt$networkModule$1$4.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.create(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:40)
        at org.koin.core.instance.SingleInstanceFactory.get(SingleInstanceFactory.kt:48)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
```

Interceptor A where it works:

```
class xUrlInterceptor constructor(
    
    private val prefData: SharedPrefDataSource,
    private val tokenApi: TokenApi,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) : Interceptor, CoroutineScope {
}
```

Interceptor B where it doesn't:

```
class AuthInterceptor constructor(
    private val tokenApi: TokenApi,
    private val prefData: SharedPrefDataSource,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository

) : Interceptor, CoroutineScope {
```

The implementation of the Repository I need to inject:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl constructor(
    private val customerApi: CustomerApi,
    private val prefData: SharedPrefDataSource,
    moshi: Moshi
) : UserRepository
```

The Koin module:

```
val androidModule = module {
    single<SharedPreferences> { PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(androidApplication()) }  
}  

val networkModule = module {
   single {  xUrlInterceptor(  
            prefData = get(),
            tokenApi = get(),
            userRepository = get()
       )}
   single { AuthInterceptor(
           tokenApi = get(),
           prefData = get(),
           userRepository = get()
    )}
```